# Python Selenium Find Element

Tags: python, selenium

I'm searching for a tag in class.I tried many methods but I couldn't get the value.

[see source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpqe9.jpg)

The data I need is inside the "data-description".
How can i get the "data-description" ?

I Tried some method but didn't work
driver.find_element_by_name("data-description")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("data-description")

I Solved this method:

```
icerisi = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('integratedService ')
for mycode in icerisi:
    hizmetler.append(mycode.get_attribute("data-description"))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you reproduce the code and the url you're trying to access? It depends alot on the web page and its elements.

Comment: @AbhasMehrotra Hi, you can find the code.https://pastebin.pl/view/c01cc8e7

Answer (score 0):

I think css selector would work best here. "data-description" isn't an element, it's an attribute of an element. The css selector for an element with a given attribute would be:

```
[attribute]
```

Or, to be more specific, you could use:

```
[attribute="attribute value"]
```

Comment: i will try the your method

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good tip:

Most web browsers have a way of copying an elements Selector or XPATH. For example, in Safari if you view the source code then right-click on an element it will give you the option to copy it. Then select XPATH or Selector and in your code use `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` or `driver.find_element_by_css_selector()`. I am certain Google Chrome and Firefox have similar options.

This method is not always failsafe, as the XPATH can be very specific, meaning that slight changes to the website will cause your script to crash, but it is a quick and easy solution, and is especially useful if you don't plan on reusing your code months or years later.

Comment: Probably xpath good choice. But getting me another data. I added screnshoot https://imgur.com/ERLscZQ

Comment: Do you mind sending me a link to the website? I find it easier to work with than screenshots or copies of the source code

Comment: logging in with a special membership but you can find the source code https://pastebin.pl/view/c01cc8e7